# Bluetooth mute unmute button for Zoom

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, bluetooth

I’m trying to map the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> keyboard shortcut through the Bluetooth button on my [selfie stick remote](https://www.amazon.in/POPIO-Bluetooth-Controller-Shutter-Compatible/dp/B0912XTYLZ) to mute/unmute Zoom meetings.

Anyone got any ideas on how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does this device come with a Ubuntu driver?

Comment: Its bluetooth device, and is able to pair

Comment: My question still stands you expect to use its features does it have a driver?

Comment: It isn't designed for desktop computers. It is designed for iOS and Android. I wouldn't expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working through a software called AutoKey.

Basically the bluetooth remote sends volume up key when pressed after being paired. Through Autokey, I was able to capture it and map it to alt+a keyboard shortcut.